# Stop all checkins except merges?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, tfs

I have this problem where I'm merging changes up into my integration branch but when I need to work on development I forget to switch back to the development branch. Are there any solutions out there available to help prevent me from editing the to Integration branch except while I'm merging in new code?

In other words, I'd like either some kind of visual cue that tells me I'm in the Integration branch, or some way to prevent myself from checking out files from the Integration branch for editing.

... or maybe I just need some Ritalin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Merge Only Checkin Policy](http://leon.mvps.org/Tfs/MergeOnlyPolicy.html) does exactly that.

Like all checkin policies, it's only as secure as the client; you can't force someone to install it.  In TFS 2010, [merging is its own permission](http://blogs.msdn.com/mitrik/archive/2009/11/10/new-branch-and-merge-permissions.aspx) so you can control it from the server side as well.